# How to add packages to Ubuntu 11.04 Install DVD?

Tags: 11.04, live-cd, customization

How can I add packages to the original Ubuntu install DVD.
I'm studing Math at university so after installing Ubuntu on my PC I downloaded math packages from the Ubuntu  repositories and I try to add debs to DVD but I can't. I use APTONCD but it creates a second dvd I only want a all my debs in one dvd. I used UCK but it only add packages in live session. I want to add all my debs and install in other pc with my math packages. Is there any way?

Answer (score 3):

To Remaster a Ubuntu CD/DVD/USB you have to use:

*A)* The [**Ubuntu LiveCD Wiki**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)

*B)* [**remastersys**](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=8&sqi=2&ved=0CGIQFjAH&url=http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/remastersys.html&ei=mJHVTYOBOsfL0QG1tfi0Bw&usg=AFQjCNGokNW_pFcNk6dhVlQiR6_r7dHYDQ&sig2=zIhG8iY9k64fzNHSk2lbmg)

[image: Remastersys]

*C)* **[Ubuntu Customization Kit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/files/)**

[image: UCK]

I, personally suggest you to use UCK, which is more user-friendly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your anwswer. I tried Ubuntu Customization kit but it only add packages in live session not in install session. I want to install my dvd (with my math packages inside) in my friends pc. Ah I forgot my friends dont have internet. After install ubuntu I want to go Synaptic and choose for example geogebra and install. I dont known if u understand me? sorry for my english I speak spanish.

Comment: yes it adds up to the live session and then it installs them once the os is installed just like any software that already comes with it.

Comment: Hi Uri, I will try UCK I hope it works maybe I need to study UCK. Thanks for your help..

Comment: Hi everybody, Well after try UCK I can say it only add debs in live session and debs are only available in live session. After install the new customization DVD I look for new debs in synaptic but there arent there. Im disappointed maybe I made something wrong. Please help me..

Comment: Hi everybody, Well after try UCK I can say it only add debs in live session and debs are only available in live session. After install the new customization DVD I look for new debs in synaptic but there arent there. Im disappointed maybe I made something wrong. Please help me..

Comment: if you add software to the livecd  like, eg. AWN latest version, from a PPA you have to add the PPA to the repositories of the livecd, i know, 'cause i installed faenza icons and the equinox themes and once i installed it to my VM drive it had both themes installed by default.

Answer (score 1):

**En Ingles:**

You could optionally add the debs to the install DVD in a separate folder, and then manually install them after installing Ubuntu.

For example:

`sudo dpkg -i /media/cdrom/packagefolder/*`

---

**En Español, de Google Translate:**

Si lo desea, puede añadir los debs para el DVD de instalación en una carpeta aparte, y luego instalarlos manualmente después de instalar Ubuntu.

Por ejemplo:

`sudo dpkg -i /media/cdrom/packagefolder/*`

Lo siento por errores, si los hay.