# How to make my own ubuntu disc?

Tags: 10.10, live-cd, customization, remastersys

One of my friend dont have internet connection but he wants to try ubuntu. I just want to install all the required packages and plugins in my machine. And i want to make this complete setup with installed packages in a seperate disc and install it in another system. Is it possible ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/43786/modification-on-usb-bootable-drive/43788#43788

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1663191

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8591740#post8591740

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/43954/how-to-add-packages-to-ubuntu-11-04-install-dvd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this question:
You can do it with remasterysys!

[How can I easily remaster Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5458/how-can-i-easily-remaster-ubuntu)